# Crear consulta en mysql estableciendo dos columnas del mismo campo dependiendo del id del año

Tags: mysql

Amigos me podrían ayudar!!!
Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: Datos de la tabla]

Y me gustaría obtener el siguiente resultado con una consulta
[image: Resultado de la consulta]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué dificultades tienes? Con un [`CASE ... WHEN ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) podrías resolverlo con suma facilidad.

Comment: Hola antonio, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: El problema con el CASE es que no me muestra las columnas a la par, es decir, me muestra primero los montos del ejercicio 71 y en la columna del monto ejercicio 139 me lo muestra en null, y una vez que se mostraron todos los montos del ejercicio 71, ahora si muestra los montos del campo "monto ejercicio 139" hasta abajo no a la par